# DialogFragment - get current orientation

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am using a DialogFragment to display an imageview with buttons below. However when I change the orientation, the button below the imageview are not shown anymore (the size of the imageview is being set dynamically programmatically).

How can I check the current orientation of the DialogFragment?

Comment: please elaborate your problem, post the code snip where you need help, so you will get better help from community

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve the current orientation, this way:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
```

from the doc:

Overall orientation of the screen. May be one of
`ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`, `ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the orientation with below code in your java file and do whatever you want..with your logic...

```
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                Log.d("ORIENTATION_TEST", "Welcome to LANDSCAPE Mode");
                Toast.makeText(this, "It is in LANDSCAPE MODE now.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                Log.d("ORIENTATION_TEST", "Welcome to PORTRAIT Mode");
                Toast.makeText(this, "It is in PORTRAIT MODE now.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that onConfigurationChanged is also called within a Fragment?

Comment: Yes...it is. For you, I've even looked at Developer.android.com and there is NO special mention of fragments in this case...